# Múltiplas instâncias do mesmo serviço windows

Tags: windows, services

Tenho um serviço rodando no **Windows**, mas o cliente necessita que o mesmo serviço funcione no mesmo servidor para fazer rotinas diferentes. Me deparei com o seguinte problema, se eu instalar o mesmo serviço com o nome igual ele alerta que já tenho um serviço instalado. Usei o seguinte comando do **SC.exe**

```
SC CREATE <name> binpath= <caminho> start= auto displayname= "<displayname>"
```

Não tive sucesso ao tentar instalar, pesquisando na internet observei que deve informar o domínio e password para que eu consiga instalar uma múltipla instância do serviço.

```
SC CREATE <name> binpath= <caminho> start= auto displayname= "<displayname>" obj= "nome do dominio" password= "senha do utilizador"
```

Queria ver se alguém já passou pela mesma experiencia e podia me ajudar a resolver. Obrigado

Comment: Que tal colocar uma tarefa agendada? Pelo agendador de tarefas você pode colocar para executar ao inciar o computador ou até mesmo no logon do usuário.

Comment: @LaércioLopes para eu fazer isso os dois serviços devem está instalados, certo?

Comment: Não, não precisa ter os serviços instalados, basta criar as tarefas pelo agendador de tarefas. Se o SO for Windows 7 ou superior execute o `taskschd.msc`. Ou vá em Painel de Controle > Ferramentas Administrativas > Agendador de Tarefas. Se for executar a tarefa sem precisar que o usuário esteja logado é necessário marcar a opção "Executar estando o usuário conectado ou não". Precisará colocar a senha do usuário e se mudar a senha posteriormente tem que clicar para alterar a tarefa e depois dar OK para salvar a nova senha.

Comment: Com isso eu consigo criar múltiplas instâncias do serviço?... com o mesmo nome rodando na mesma máquina

Comment: Se o executável permitir consegue sim, mas uma tarifa agendada não vai ser um serviço.